# Wired Network - Nothing Shown

Tags: ethernet, connection, wired

I can't see the 'Wired Connection' information when I go to Preferences > Network.

I can see Wireless, but nothing about Wired Connection, not even when I hook an Ethernet patch lead into the RJ-45 port socket. Do I need to re-install the drivers or network service again?

Anyone knows how this can be solved please?

Someone can perhaps give me a response on this?

Comment: @K7AAY and I would also like to see: `lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3`  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @Daniel_Patrick, please advise 1) Which version number of Ubuntu is in use? 2) 64-bit or 32-bit? 3) Result of cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "model name" && sudo lshw | grep -A5 "Moth" && lshw | grep product | head -n1 && cat /proc/net/dev && lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3 && sudo lshw -class network && nmcli Please collect that information and add it to your question by clicking [edit] then pasting the data into your question, to help us help you. Please do not use Add Comment; instead, use [edit].

Comment: Possibly `dmesg | egrep -i 'eth|net|err'` would shed light. Should be done shortly after reboot in case there is something logging heavily to dmeg.

Comment: Anyone knows how this can be solved?